# How to get python file name in decorator function in inherited file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main class and inherited class. I have a decorator function in main class.
This following code in base.py.

```
def functionErrorCase(functionParam):
    def wrapper(self):
        try:
            functionParam(self)
        except Exception as e:
            self.InsertError(os.path.basename(__file__), functionParam.__name__)
    return wrapper
```

Used in all functions in inherited class
"__ file __" Command return base.py file name but i want the filename of the used class

How to return the used class file name ?

Comment: Are you aware of the ``.__module__`` attribute, the ``inspect`` and ``traceback`` module??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global variable `__file__` is always going to have the filename of the module you read it in. If your code is in `base.py`, that's the file name it's going to find. To read the file from another module, you'll need to read `__file__` from its globals. Conveniently, you can access the globals of a function through its `__globals__` attribute. So you could try `functionParam.__globals__['__file__']`.

But there may be an even better option that doesn't require using `__file__` at all. Python functions have a `__module__` attribute that names the module that they're defined in. If you don't need the `.py` at the end of the file name, that might be more useful than `__file__`. You might also consider using the `__qualname__` of the function instead of the regular `__name__`, since the former will include the name of any class the function is declared in (e.g. `"Foo.bar"` for the `bar` method of the `Foo` class).

Comment: Note that ``__qualname__`` does not include the module name, only the path *inside* the module. The ``__module__`` holds the module name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Thanks for the correction. I've edited my answer to state things correctly. `__qualname__` is still valuable, but in this context you're entirely right that `__module__` is more what the questioner wants.

Comment: FWIW, I think `functionParam.__globals__['__file__']` is what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you Blckknght for answer the question. i  writed functionParam.__globals__['__ file __'] command then is worked